# Color profile issues with PNG images

Tags: facebook, colors, png

I posted this here because it's too technical and related to the PNG standard.

I did the following:

**Step 1**. Open paint, create an image and fill it with color RGB(255, 0, 0) = #FF0000. Save the image.

**Step 2**. Download [tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) and remove all Attributes except those marked as 'critical'. By doing this we effectively remove any color profile information. This will make our image to be displayed the same across all browsers (FireFox and Chrome tested) otherwise firefox displays the image as dark red.

**Step 3**. If I upload this image on facebook, strange things happen. FireFox and Chrome display a dark red color. This happens because Facebook [adds a custom color profile](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-improving-facebook-photos/10150630639853920) to all images uploaded.

**Question**: How can I prevent Facebook from adding the extra color profile and altering the colors of my image? If this is not possible, how can I modify my image in a way so I get the desired color after Facebook added their color profile?

Comment: You can disable the color correction in Firefox (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox)), but I have a feeling that won't be the solution to your problem...

Comment: @Mr Lister: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't ask every visitor to modify their browser just to see my images correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened:

At first I uploaded the image on Facebook without removing the color profile. I deleted the image and then uploaded the new without the color profile.

For some reason the browser cached the old image.

After I restarted the PC and cleared the browser cache... the colors where the ones I expected!